# as3 air convert sequence of bitmaps to flv

Tags: actionscript-3, air

It's posible convert an image sequence (jpg, png) to .flv (or .mp4 instead), using AS3/AIR?

I'm developing an app. This app must record video on an Android tablet.

As the "CameraUI" class doesn't permit to put images/design over the camera capture, and I need to overlay branded design,

I'm trying to save a sequence of bitmaps using [this Starling extension](http://www.flintfabrik.de/blog/starling-webcamvideo-extension) (Using this extension I can overlay desing and it's manage a good performance).

My idea is take the generated image sequence, convert it to video, and then to delete the original bitmap files.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. FLV is an open format. Easiest way is to create raw flv. Otherwise you need to search for the proper compression (there are libraries online).
For the first one, there are a few very old posts, but I think the idea is the same. Few can be found here:
http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/
http://www.joristimmerman.be/wordpress/2008/12/18/flvrecorder-record-to-flv-using-air/

Try to search for 'flv recorder'. There are few out, even with compression and audio.